# Geth - Web3 : Invalid number of parameters for "MyMethod". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, nodejs

I'm using Web3.js (@1.0) and not @0.2

This is really annoying !

My Private blockchain is running thanks to the following command : v`geth --datadir "T:\Programs\Ethereum\Own\" --networkid 2154 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" console`

Here, how a deploy my contract: (deploy.js)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledContract = require('./App');
const localhost = "http://localhost:8545";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(localhost));
const App = new web3.eth.Contract(compiledContract.abi);

var deployInstance = App.deploy({data: compiledContract.bytecode});
deployInstance.estimateGas(function(err, gas){
   console.log("gasestimate " + gas);
   web3.eth.getCoinbase().then(function(coinbase){
     console.log("coinbase " + coinbase);
     deployInstance.send({from: coinbase, gas: gas+4000}, function(error, transactionHash){})
  .on('transactionHash', function(hash){console.log("hash : " + hash); })
  .on('receipt', function (receipt) { console.log("Address: " + receipt.contractAddress); })
  .on('error', console.error);
   });
});
```

That's working pretty good, and my contract is deployed.
I obviously though to unlock an account (here eth.coinbase) and to call `miner.start()` and `miner.stop()` when the contract was finally mined

Then that's how I call my methods. This is a sample code: (call.js)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledContract = require('./App');
const localhost = "http://localhost:8545";
const address = "0x84C210471f7C58b547129E62cdDC2D365d307212"; //address returned after deployed phase

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(localhost));
var Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(compiledContract.abi, address);

set();
//get();

function get(){
   Contract.methods.getTest().call(function(err, result){
     if(err) console.log(err);
     else console.log(result);
   });
}

function set(){
   web3.eth.getCoinbase().then(function(coinbase){
      web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(coinbase, "", function(err) {
        Contract.methods.setTest("ugonnawork").send({from: coinbase, gas: 300000}, function(error, transactionHash){})
    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){console.log("hash : " + hash); })
    .on('error', console.error);
  });
 });
}
```

And this annoying issue occurred :

```
Geth - Web3 : Invalid number of parameters for "MyMethod". Got 0 expected 1!
```

When I call another method called `getUser(uint index)` I got : `Geth - Web3 : Invalid number of parameters for "MyMethod". Got 1 expected 2!`

And when I call name() that's working pretty good, and my ERC20 Token name is returned.

It seems that fails or works randomly but it can't figure out what's wrong

Please help

Comment: I had similar issues, but mine were related to using the 1.0 web3.js API. Mind posting your contract or ABI code if you're still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes I figured out by downgrading to 0.2 but it was so many months ago. I don't know what's going on nowadays..